# handling bottom line inside a table

Tags: html, css

i am trying to handle the bottom lines inside a table (i want to cut them a bit to the right)

[image]

here is my table code:

```
<table class="reportTable">
     <thread>
          <tr>
                <th>firstColumn</th>
                <th>secondColumn</th>
                <th>thirdColumn</th>
          </tr>
     </thread>
     <tbody>
          <tr>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>3</td> 
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td>11</td>
               <td>22</td>
               <td>33</td> 
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td>111</td>
               <td>222</td>
               <td>333</td> 
          </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

and here is my css code:

```
.reportTable th,td{
      border-bottom: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
      border-right:16px solid transparent;

 }
```

Comment: Is what you have not working? It appears to be for me.

Comment: nope i want to handle the right border and add some more spaces between the columns, when the width of the column is set to a specific number it doesn't work

Comment: to be more exact... if you try to add more spaces (change the bottom right pixel number it only adds to the width of the column and not getting the spaces between every two columns larger

Comment: so do you want to make the lines longer or shorter?

Comment: i want the lines to stay as they are and only change the line between them (to be larger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add border-spacing to the table and position it relative with a negative left to push it back to it's original spot.

http://jsfiddle.net/hyn1db04/3/

```
<table class="reportTable">
 <thread>
      <tr>
            <th>firstColumn</th>
            <th>secondColumn</th>
            <th>thirdColumn</th>
      </tr>
 </thread>
 <tbody>
      <tr>
           <td>1</td>
           <td>2</td>
           <td>3</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
           <td>11</td>
           <td>22</td>
           <td>33</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
           <td>111</td>
           <td>222</td>
           <td>333</td> 
      </tr>
 </tbody>
```

CSS

```
.reportTable {
border-spacing: 30px 0;
}
.reportTable th, .reportTable td {
border-bottom: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
position: relative;
left: -30px;
}
```

EDIT:
Alternatively, you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/m021e4gh/8/

```
.reportTable th,td {
border-bottom: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
}

table td + td, table th + th { 
position: relative;
left: 30px; 
}

table td + td + td, table th + th + th { 
position: relative;
left: 60px; 
}
```

Add a width if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is the `border-spacing` property in CSS:

```
.reportTable {
    border-spacing: 10px 0;
}
.reportTable th, .reportTable td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
    border-right: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
}
```

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hyn1db04/)

Comment: nice and thank but the thing with line spacing is that it pushes the first column to the right as well , do you know how to avoid it ?